# Will Clojure run on Azure Now?

Tags: clojure, azure

I saw that Microsoft announced Java support on Azure today at PDC.  Does that mean it will be able to run Clojure (and other JVM languages) as well?

Comment: If Clojure runs on Azure I'll have a seizure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in short yes. clojure can directly call java. It would be very nice to get some clojure wrappers to ease the general boiler-plate-ness.

Comment: See https://coderead.wordpress.com/2014/04/16/running-clojure-on-azure-web-sites/ for a short "getting started" summary